# Input a check_box_tag value into a Rails model from outside the main form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm developing a marketplace app. Sellers list products to sell. I want to create a featured listings widget. So I created an admin page where I can see all listed items. Then added a check box for "featured" on the admin page so I can select which items I want to be featured.

Then I did a migration to add 'featured' as a boolean field in my listing model.

How do I insert a form_for in my admin page html below so the check box value is input as 1(or true) into the listing model?

Once I get the check box value to the model, I can add the method to my controller to filter for featured listings.

```
<div class="center">
 <h2>Admin area: All Listings</h2>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
  <th>Image</th>
  <th>Seller</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Featured</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>

<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= image_tag listing.image.url(:thumb) %></td>
  <td><%= listing.userid %></td>
  <td><%= listing.name %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></td>
  <td><%= check_box_tag(:featured) %></td>
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><%= link_to "View", listing, class: "btn btn-link" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_listing_path(listing), class: "btn btn-link" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Delete', listing, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-link" %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: For example, if i want to show 10 featured products on the homepage, and i want to change those products every few days. I want to be able to go to the admin page and check/uncheck as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through javascript, there are many methods but a simple solution would be in your form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :featured, class: 'hidden' %>
```

In your checkbox:

```
<%= check_box_tag(:featured_checkbox), data: {id: listing.id}  %> #or whatever
```

and append those values this way (jquery):

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        $('.hidden').value($(this).data('id'))
    });
});
```

Disclaimer: not tested but it should work.

EDIT:
Make sure that the jquery snippet is executed on document ready. See above edited.

If you need to parse the value of the checkbox, the data should be saved even if it's not, you  could do it through cookies. If the record is saved:

```
<%= check_box_tag(:featured_checkbox), value: listing.featured, data: {id: listing.id}  %>
```

Anyway, it's more important to understand the procedure than make this code work (as is).

Comment: Could you spell this out for me a little more. I entered the hidden_field in my new listing form. I entered the check_box_tag and the js in my admin page. Is that right? That doesn't update my model 'featured' field to 1. And when I refresh the admin page, the check box is blank again. I need to be able to change the featured items as needed so the check box needs to be editable in that when I check it, the model field is 1, when I uncheck, it goes back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would implement this via JS/jQuery and a nice post/get request back to server, it feels like this would be a better UX approach.  However, I've also added a rough idea for the form approach too.

**JS Approach**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    $.get('/listings/admin/feature_listing/'+$(this).val(), function(data){
      alert("Listing has been toggled!");
    });
  });
});
```

Don't forget to update your routes file for this.

**Form Approach**

You'd basically have to break out a new form and seperate the :featured attribute out.

```
<%= form_tag listing_featured_path, method: :get do %>
<td><%= check_box_tag "listing_featured", "Featured", :value=>listing.featured %></td>
<td><%= submit_tag "Submit" %></td>
<% end %>
```

You will then need to create a new seperate action in your controller to pick up that custom param and also update routes.

Comment: Thanks, to clarify, if I take the JS approach, where do I put the JS? In the featured listing html page? And if I do that, then that page just updates with featured listings as I check/uncheck the check boxes in the admin page? Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Updating via a get request is icky.

Comment: @Moosa as a good practice you should put it in application-jquery.js.  But you can also put it at the bottom of your featured listing page.  And once thats done, you need to add the route, and add the controller action.  Yes it will work on one checkbox at a time, you can see if its working by using your chrome dev tools inspector and have a look at the Network tab.

Comment: Why do you do a get instead of post? If checkbox is checked/unchecked, I want to post that value to the model so I can use it later in different views. Could you give me the form approach for this? The JS solution doesn't work as I intended it to.

Comment: You can do either get or post, as i said above...  The form based solution is above too.  Those are 2 separate solutions.

Comment: To write to a model, wouldn't I need a form_for? Looks like I'm missing some basics...will review the api docs. I created my route. The used your form code in my admin html - the view looks like I want it to but when I hit submit, I get an error saying "couldn't find listing with id=featured"

Comment: Watch this Railscasts, should clear things up to why we use form_tag not form_for in this case; http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised

Comment: I followed railscast #52 and am close to getting to the solution. Here is a follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298282/rails-4-partials-to-make-a-copy-of-another-view