# Rails 4 Partials to make a copy of another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an ecommerce app and am trying to create a featured items widget. I have a featured items view, which is linked to a controller method that filters for featured items. The view is featured.html.erb. I created a copy of the file and named it _featured.html.erb to be the partial.

However, when I render the partial on the homepage as below, it doesn't call the controller method so I don't get the featured filter applied.

```
<%= render 'featured' %>
```

Is there an option to tell rails to use the same controller method on the partial? Or is there a different way to do this?

Comment: If I do understand what you mean; you have 2 controller and you are trying to retrieve the same partials. At first I need to told you that it doesn't seems right to me. Can you explain more.

Comment: I have one controller and one view. I want to render the view as a widget on another view page so I want a partial. But the partial doesn't read the method in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a scope to your Item model and not perform filtering logic in controller.

Let's say in yor Item model

```
scope :featured, -> { where(featured: true) } # or any logic you have
```

Then in your controller action that renders home page, you should do

```
@items = Item.featured
```

then in your home page view you can render partial and pass items to it

```
render 'your_path_to\featured', items: @items
```

so in '_featured' partial you can access items

```
items.each do |item|
```

Than you can DRY your code by rendering '_featured' partial in in 'featured.html.erb' and setting @items variable in action that renders the view.